# When to use investigate, and when investigate into?

Tags: word-usage

I am translating a text about investigations by the International Criminal Court. I see "investigate into" in various references, but find only "investigate" in the dictionaries. Are both correct? When do you use one and when the other?

Comment: It's poor use of English: "investigate" means "look into".

Comment: Agreed. You can "investigate" or you can "look into", but the closest to "investigate into" that is good English is, for example, "_The ICC set up **an investigation into** the war crimes of X_"

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the comments from Weather Vane and Peter Jennings - in most cases "investigate" implies "into", and out of context "investigate into" looks like sloppy shorthand for "carry out an investigation into".

More information on the context would have been useful. For example "The doorman allowed the detectives who had been assigned to investigate into the building." would be correct English - though commas, parentheses or dashes around "who had been assigned to investigate" would improve clarity.